# Strings customization for Smooch's web widget not working

Tags: smooch

I'm trying to customize the text strings of my Smooch's web widget (I need them to be in Spanish).

I'm using the example code provided in the documentation, but the strings in the widget are not being replaced...

Here's my snippet:

```js
<script src="https://cdn.smooch.io/smooch.min.js"></script>
<script>
Smooch.init({
    appToken: 'mytoken',
    customText: {
        headerText: 'Cómo podemos ayudarte?',
        inputPlaceholder: 'Escribí un mensaje...',
        sendButtonText: 'Enviar',
    }
});
</script>
```

And here's the link to my site in case you'd like to check the widget in action: https://www.terapiapoint.com/psicologos-online-para-expatriados/

Answer (score 1):

Sigh... This is embarrassing but I realized the issue was as stupid as this:

I just copied the example code, which had a comma that shouldn't be there after the last string... I removed that comma and everything's working now :)